# this operation is not supported in the wcf test client because it uses type system.object[] error using WCF and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, wcf, entity

I am trying to create a WCF with Generic methods where it is going to received IList of different objects, so once the IList comes in with a string that will tell the type of object, them the method will validate and call a function accordingly.

When I "Build" the WCF project, it completes successfully.
But testing the WCF with the Built in WCF Test Client, I cannot test the it because each method I set to get published, are showing the "this operation is not supported in the wcf test client because it uses type system.object[]" error

this is my Contract code:

```
            namespace WCF_RENTACAR
            {
                    [ServiceContract]
                    public interface IRentacar
                    {
                        [OperationContract]
                        void insert(string tObjeto, IList objet);

                        [OperationContract]
                        void update(string tObjet, int id, IList objet);
                    }

            }
```

Then the methods are set this way:

```
            namespace WCF_RENTACAR
            {
                    {
                        Rentacar_Entities db = new Rentacar_Entities();

                        public void insertar(string tObject, IList object)
                        {
                                string type = tObjet;

                            if (type == "user")
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                            TB_SEG_USERS u= new TB_SEG_USERS();

                                        foreach (TB_SEG_USERS item in object)
                                            {
                                                string e = item.DESCRIPCION;
                                                u.DESCRIPCION = e;

                                                agregarEstado(u);
                                            }
                                                object.Clear();
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {

                                    }
                                }
                        }

                        public void update(string tObject, int id, IList object)
                        {
                                string type = tObject;

                            if (type == "user")
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        TB_SEG_USERS u= new TB_SEG_USERS();

                                        foreach (TB_SEG_ESTADOS item in objeto)
                                            {
                                                string e = item.DESCRIPCION;
                                                u.DESCRIPCION = e;

                                                agregarEstado(est);
                                            }
                                            object.Clear();
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {

                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
```

I have Entity Models in my WCF Project, and on my DAL layer

Some one have an idea what should I do

Thank you

Comment: what does  agregarEstado() do? also, I think it gets confused because the arguments in your functions are called object, while this is a type descriptor.

Comment: It will basically add a new object to the database
the problem seems to be related with the generic List
Talking about insertar(), that is to insert object in the database
So I need it to get a generic list, so then I can call a function that will insert the specific object will be coming up